# Late Answer delete activity not registered in moderator activity history

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

A late answer came in for a question: [Simple JavaScript Backbone.Js tool to highlight multiple search terms](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/77496/31503). This late answer then appeared in the Late Answer review queue: [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/32182).

I picked up this review as part of my regular review activity, and determined that the answer should be converted to a comment. I performed the following actions:

1. edited the answer so that it was formatted in a more comment-like way
2. mod->convert-to-comment

This has had the desired effect, but, there are two side-effects which are absent:

1. the review is not 'registered' as a review - it does not appear in the [Late Answer review history](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/history).
2. More concerning, the convert-to-comment is a moderator action, and it does not appear in my moderation activity history. The general admin dashboard shows:

[image]

but my actual history shows:

[image]

I would expect that the delete should show there. Something like this previous activity here:

[image]

I believe there may be a bug related to accessing the post from the review queue that causes the audit trail to be lost?